# Are there Admin settings for enabling/disabling the macro recorder in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

After activating the Developer tab on the Excel ribbon, I noticed the Record Macro, Visual Basic, and Macros button's are disabled. I have been installing macros to the Personal.xlsb files for years and this is the first time I am unable to create the Personal.xlsb file using the Record Macro button.

Is there an admin setting, perhaps at install that would turn these features off? This issue is isolated to a single new user at present.

Comment: If it's an enterprise installation they could be disabled by the administrator.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here?  https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+record+macro+button+greyed+out